# Code in Python that count repeated elements and return the item repeated most times and how many times

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, pycharm, counting

I have a list with integers, I need to find which item repeat the most, then the function should return two variables (value, number) value is the repeated element and number is the times that repeated

input

```
B = [1, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1]
```

output

```
1 3
```

I got a code that works with the first item in the list, but when it goes to the next loop it start everything in zero, so I was struggling to store what I got in the first loop and compare with the second loop to see which one I need to keep.

For this function I am not allowed to use any module or library like "count" or any other advanced code, just as simple as it can be for a rookie level

```
def counting(B):
   n = len(B)
   tempcount = []
   tempcval = []

   for i in range(0,n-1):
      cval=B[i]
      count = 0

      for next in B:
         if next == cval:
              count += 1

         tempcount.append(count)
         tempcval.append(cval)

      return count,cval

def main():
   list = [1, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1]
   a,b = counting(list)
   print(a,b)

main()
```

expected output

```
3 1
```

actual output

```
2 5
```

Comment: dictionary should be the most straight answer, use the item in list as key and value as the count. the only caveat is remember to  test key existence with "in" before accessing any value

Comment: Note: Your `return` statement is inside the for-loop, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution could be to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> import collections
>>> c = collections.Counter([1, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1])
>>> c
Counter({1: 3, 5: 2, 3: 1})
>>> c.most_common(1)
[(1, 3)]
```

In a function this could look like this:

```
import collections

def counting(the_list):
    c = collections.Counter(the_list)
    data = c.most_common(1)[0]
    print('value', data[0])
    print('count', data[1])

    return data[1], data[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm familiar with pandas, dataframe manipulating library

If I were you, I will use

```
import pandas as pd
temp = pd.Series([1, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1])
temp2 = temp.value_counts()
temp2.index[0], temp2.iloc[0]
```

But the first answer seems more simple hahaha

Answer (score 0):

A solution using nothing requiring any imports. Your code had some issues in that you never actually used those tempcount and tempcvals. You'd append to them, but nothing else. I took them along for the ride this time and am using them to store the counts of each value, basically turning tempcval into a non duplicate list of the inputted list.

```
def counting(B):
   n = len(B)
   tempcount = []
   tempcval = []

   for next in B:
      if next in tempcval:
         point = tempcval.index(next)
         tempcount[point] = tempcount[point] + 1
      else:
         tempcval.append(next)
         tempcount.append(1)

   maxCount = max(tempcount)
   point = tempcount.index(maxCount)

   return tempcount[point],tempcval[point]

def main():
   list = [1, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1]
   a,b = counting(list)
   print(a,b)

main()
```

So there is one issue with this code. It works in the example given, but say you gave

```
list = [1, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5]
```

the code would still return 3 1 since the 1 appeared before the 5.

Answer (score 0):

This question looks to be solved, but here's a spin using the `collections.Counter` method:

```py
from collections import Counter

my_list = [1, 5, 1, 3, 5, 1, 5]
my_list_counted = Counter(my_list)
most_common_items = my_list_counted.most_common(len(my_list_counted))
print(most_common_items[0][0], most_common_items[-1][0])
```

```
>>> 1 3
```